# How to prove an inequality to do with Van der Waerden's function

Tags: functions, inequality

I am given that the function g(x) = |x - k|, where k is the nearest integer to x. From this, I am supposed to prove that this function $\frac{g(x)-g(x+t)}{t}$ $\leq$ 1 for all x and all t $\gt$ 0 (all t below zero are implied by this too). There's several cases I've already covered:

t>1/2, 0$\leq$g(x)$\leq$1/2 so therefore g(x)-g(y) can be 1/2 at most. This means that the lhs is always less than $\frac{1}{2x}$, makng it trivial for all such t.

t<1/2, g(x) has the same k as g(x+t). By simple application of the triangle inequality:

$$\frac{|x+t-k|-|x-k|}{t} \leq \frac{|x-k|+|t|-|x-k|}{t} = \frac{|t|}{t} = 1$$

For the other case though, where the k of g(x+t) is k+1 for g(x), then I struggle. It makes intuitive sense that it is, but doing the same triangle inequality process gives me $1 + \frac{1}{t}$, which is less useful. Does anyone have any clue?

Thank you!

EDIT: Just so you can see a geometric understanding (and the reason why I feel so stupid about it) is that essentially I'm trying to prove that a line from one to the other section has gradient less than or equal to 1, which is obvious from the picture but I'm not sure how to prove it
[image: function plotted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that $g$ is linear with slope $+1$ or $-1$ on each closed interval $[\frac{j}{2}, \frac{j+1}{2}]$, $j \in \Bbb Z$.

For $x < y$ let
$$
  a_1 < a_2 < \ldots < a_{n-1} 
$$
be the (possibly empty) sequence of all "half integers" between $x$ and $y$. Setting $a_0 = x$, $a_n = y$ we have that $g$ is linear with
slope $\pm 1$ on each interval $[a_{j-1}, a_j]$, and
$$ 
 |g(y) -g(x) |= \left| \sum_{j=1}^n g(a_j) - g(a_{j-1}) \right |
 \le \sum_{j=1}^n |g(a_j) - g(a_{j-1})|
 \\
= \sum_{j=1}^n |a_j - a_{j-1} | = \sum_{j=1}^n (a_j - a_{j-1}) = y - x
$$

More generally, if $I_1, \ldots, I_n$ are "adjacent" intervals and a function $g$ is Lipschitz-continuous (with the same Lipschitz constant
$L$) on each interval $I_j$, then $g$ is Lipschitz-continuous on 
the union of the intervals.

---

*Alternative approach:* Let $x < y$ and $k = \lfloor x + \frac 12 \rfloor$, $l = \lfloor y + \frac 12 \rfloor$ be the nearest integers
to $x$ and $y$, respectively.

*Case 1:* $l = k$. Then
$$
 |g(y) - g(x)| = ||y-k| - |x-k|| \le |(y-k) - (x-k)| = y - x \, .
$$

*Case 2:* $l = k+1$. Then
$$
|g(y) - g(x)| = \bigl||y-(k+1)| - |x-k| \bigr| \\
 \le \bigl| |y-(k+1)| - \frac 12 \bigr| + \bigl| \frac 12 - |x-k|\bigr | \\
 \le \bigl| y-(k+1) - \frac 12 \bigr| + \bigl| \frac 12 - (x-k)\bigr | \\
 = \bigl( y - (k + \frac 12) \bigr) + \bigl( (k + \frac 12) - x \bigr) \\
 = y - x \, .
$$

*Case 3:* $l \ge k + 2$. Then $y - x \ge 1$ and
$ |g(y) - g(x) | \le \frac 12 $.

Comment: This is a nice answer but not going to lie, from the material it's from (T.W. Korner's "The Pleasures of Counting", a book who is designed for first year/pre-uni but the author claims a confident 14 year old would understand) I assumed the solution was going to be much simpler. I had never heard of Lipschitz continuity, for example.

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Well, the part of Lipschitz-continuity was only an additional remark to put the problem into a more general context, the proof itself uses only the triangle inequality. – I have added another approach which might be closer to what you were thinking of, in particular the case where you "struggled" is treated in an elementary way.

Comment: that was a lot more transparent to me, thank you very much!